# Ограничение количества запросов к странице

Tags: php

Как можно сделать ограничение кол-ва запросов к php странице к примеру к 3 в 1 сек, и как это лучше реализовать?

P.s Сама страница содержит динамические `JSON` данные

Comment: самое простое по IP... чуть сложнее: связка IP + тип браузера или даже IP + тип браузера + версия браузера ....вряд ли кто-то сможет менять это чаще чем 3 раза в секунду

Comment: JSON-данные индивидуальны для юзера? Юзеры аутентифицированы?

Comment: Да да и для доступа к ним пользователь авторизуется

Comment: @RedWoolf если для доступа - юзер авторизуется, то вообще в чем вопрос? проверяте, что не гость, и задаете интервал обращения для юзера + limit обращения, которые обнуляется каждый заданный интервал (в данном случае секунда).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А вы не ограничивайте доступ, просто кэшируйте результат сохраняя его в оперативной памяти, например, в memcached со сроком хранения 3 секунды.

```
<?php
$m = new Memcached();
$m->addServer('localhost', 11211);

$json = 'error';
if (!($json = $m->get('json'))) {
  if ($m->getResultCode() == Memcached::RES_NOTFOUND) {
    // Долго и трудоемко вычисляем JSON
    $json = '{...}';
    // Устанавливаем значение на 3 секунды
    $m->add('json', $json, 3);
  }
}
echo $json;
```

Как только memcached уничтожит ключ json, скрипт не обнаружит его, снова вычислит по динамическому запросу, положит в memcached и отдаст клиенту. В промежутке между этими событиями json будет извлекаться из memcached очень быстро. Тогда вы сможете отдавать произвольное количество запросов, не подвергая нагрузке хранилища, ответственные за генерацию JSON-а. Более того, при возрастании нагрузки вы сможете увеличивать время хранения ключа, а при ее снижении, наоборот, сокращать.

Comment: но так будет ограничение вообще на доступ к странице? а если надо для каждого юзера отдельно?  .........и не на 3 секунды а на 3 запроса в секунду у ТС написано ;-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Это один из вариантов, возможно JSON вообще не меняется часами (в вопросе мало информации). Если JSON изменяется исключительно быстро, можно, как вы предлагаете хранить информацию о клиенте с заранее заданным сроком жизни (как это делается в примере), например, его IP-адрес в том же memcached (хотя наверное лучше в redis) и проверять ее наличие. Есть такой IP-адрес - возвращать отлуп, нет - отдавать JSON. Однако, по сравнению с общим кэшем эта система более хрупкая и накладная.

Comment: Ну в общем идея неплохая, на сайте юзаю memcache так что можно использовать

Answer (score 4):

Лучше реализовать это не в PHP, а средствами веб-сервера.

Напр. для **nginx** есть модуль [limit_req](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html) предназначенный как раз для вашей задачи – ограничения числа запросов в единицу времени. В примерах там приведен конфиг для ограничения по одному IP. Но вы можете задать «ключём» и несколько [переменных](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables) – напр. IP и версию браузера:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr$http_user_agent zone=one:10m rate=3r/s;
```

Comment: Я использую nginx но хотелось бы сделать на PHP

Comment: решение в любом случае будет, абстрактно, таким: в какую-то общедоступную область памяти записывается статистика предыдущих запросов, читается, и принимается решение отвечать или нет. Запрос поступает в nginx, далее передаётся в php-fpm. Вопрос: зачем гонять тяжёлый php, если можно уже на этапе nginx решить задачу.